# Rendering components based on response React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render button component based on the API response.

Button response structure

```
 "buttons": {
                   "yesButton": {
                      "buttonText": "Yes",
                   },
                   "noButton": {
                      "buttonText": "No"
                   }
                }
```

`componentContent.buttons` is returning two objects with button contents and the data is getting printed in the console.

But in the view I'm not seeing any buttons html.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
 const renderComponentButtons = () => {
if (componentContent?.buttons) {
  console.log(componentContent?.buttons);
  Object.keys(componentContent.buttons).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key);
    return (
      <ButtonAction
        aria-label={componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
        onClick={() => {
          props.toPrev();
        }}
      >
        {componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
      </ButtonAction>
    );
  });
}
};

  return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
          {renderComponentButtons()}
        </div>
      </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

-Change forEach to map and add return to the start

> renderComponentButtons()

```
const renderComponentButtons = () => {
    if (componentContent?.buttons) {
      console.log(componentContent?.buttons);
      return(Object.keys(componentContent.buttons).map((key, index) => (
        <button
        key={index}
            aria-label={componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
            onClick={() => {
              // props.toPrev();
            }}
          >
            {componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
          </button>)
      ))
          }
  };
```

visit [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leftpad-pg7q5w?file=/src/App.js:245-732) to play around with the code.

The output:
[image]

Comment: I added the return statement but still the button is not getting rendered

Comment: I've updated my code in the question,

Comment: @ArunKumar I have updated my answer please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, but you should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and return results from `renderComponentButtons`.

`forEach` is for looping through all values in an array and does not expect returned results. `map` is different, it is used to get returned results.

In your case, your buttons' components need to be returned from the loop

```
const renderComponentButtons = () => {
  if (componentContent?.buttons) {
    console.log(componentContent?.buttons);
    return Object.keys(componentContent.buttons).map((key) => {
      console.log(key);
      return (
        <ButtonAction
          aria-label={componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
          onClick={() => {
            props.toPrev();
          }}
          key={key}
        >
          {componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
        </ButtonAction>
      );
    });
  }
  return null; //no buttons in your data
};

return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-4"> {renderComponentButtons()} </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I get this error in console "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: I just added `key={key}` in the answer, you can check it out again @ArunKumar

Answer (score 0):

ForEach return `undefined` so use map instead of forEach like this

```
Object.keys(componentContent.buttons).map((key) => {   // change this line
  console.log(key);
  return (
    <ButtonAction
      aria-label={componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
      onClick={() => {
        props.toPrev();
      }}
    >
      {componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
    </ButtonAction>
  );
});
```

Using map you can avoid the return statement by replacing the curly brackets by parenthesis like this

```
Object.keys(componentContent.buttons).map((key) => ( 
  <ButtonAction
    aria-label={componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
    onClick={() => {
      props.toPrev()
    }}
  >
    {componentContent.buttons[key].buttonText}
  </ButtonAction>
)
```

Comment: Buttons are not visible with your solution